# append @Html.ActionLink to a Modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.actionlink

Here is my question;

I want to append an action link in a modal.

```
var dltlink = "@@Html.ActionLink(\"Click here\", \"About\", \"Home\", null, null)";
    $("#deleteModal").find('.modal-footer').append(dltlink);

    $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
```

But it appears as a text like @Html.ActionLink("Click here", "About", "Home", null, null) not a link.
Any idea?

Comment: You can't execute a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for 
 `var dltlink = "@@Html.ActionLink(\"Click here\", \"About\", \"Home\", null, null)";` 
 

 In javascript you can just use
 
 `var dltlink = '@Html.ActionLink("Click here", "About", "Home", null, null)';`

*Edit: Keep in mind this only works in a Razor view*

Comment: thank you so much :) it works but i want to ask you one more question.         i cant put a paramater in the link with your way. Thats why i try to turn string. For example                                                                              var   machineId =  1;                                                                             var dltlink = '@Ajax.ActionLink("Evet", "EditModal", "Machine", new {id= machineId }, new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId= "updatetr", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" }, new { @class= "btn btn-danger" })';

Comment: @ozgo you are right, using this way you can only use C# variables not javascript variables. An option would be `var text = "@Html.ActionLink( "Link text", "Action Name", new { id = "[[MYVAR]]" })"
text = text.replace("[[MYVAR]]", "A javascript var");`

Comment: that's very helpful. Thank you again:)